# Wpf screen edge swipe detect

Tags: wpf, touch, gesture

I have a basic wpf app that basically detects a touch input and moves a rectangle according to the input. My problem is that if  that touch comes outside the screen(For example: I touch the bottom bezel of the screen and slide it in the touch area) it won't be detected. Is there a way to get over this problem? I want to detect edge swipes as well.

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="touch_test.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:touch_test"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800"
        Stylus.IsPressAndHoldEnabled="False"
        >
    <Canvas>
        <Rectangle Width="50" Height="50" x:Name="rect" Fill="Red"/>
    </Canvas>

</Window>
```

Cs:

```
    protected TouchPoint TouchStart;
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
       
        this.PreviewTouchDown += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(BasePage_TouchDown);
        this.PreviewTouchMove += new EventHandler<TouchEventArgs>(BasePage_TouchMove);
        WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
        WindowStyle = WindowStyle.None;
    }
    void BasePage_TouchDown(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        TouchStart = e.GetTouchPoint(this);
    }
    void BasePage_TouchMove(object sender, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        Rectangle rectToMove = rect;
        rectToMove.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform();
        Matrix matr = ((MatrixTransform)rectToMove.RenderTransform).Matrix;
        var currentTouchPoint = e.GetTouchPoint(this);

        

        matr.Translate(currentTouchPoint.Position.X, currentTouchPoint.Position.Y );

        rectToMove.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matr);

    }
```

Comment: You might be better off using ManipulationDelta event and ManipulationStarted event if necessary.

Comment: @emoacht I tried that option as well. it doesn't work on the bottom or right edge. It does work on the left one though

Comment: Then you can explore why such difference occurs. Theoretically, Manipulation events work regardless of direction.